# VBA Error 400 while using Range with PrintArea

Tags: vba, excel

For a project, I need to print a sheet on Excel, and the area depends on events. 
As a beginner, I'm trying to work this out alone but I don't know how to.

Here's a sample of my code :

```
Dim var1 As Range
Dim var2 As Range
Dim var3 As Range

Set var1 = Range("$A$1:$A$10")
Set var2 = Range("$A$12:$A$15")

With ActiveSheet
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(var1, var2).Address
    Set var3 = Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea)
    MsgBox (rngCompany3)
End With
```

The only one thing I get is "Error 400" with no more explanations. I already know from where it is : `Set var3 = Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea)` is the reason.

I also tried `Set var3 = .Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea)` and `Set var3 = Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea.Address)` but it don't figure it out.

Please let me know if you have any ideas, I'll be glad. Thanks, Clément.

Comment: Try debugging by printing whats inside the `with` statement to the console. `Debug.Print .PageSetup.PrintArea`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. What's `rngCompany3`? if this is a snippet of your code, then it's likely that something else causes the error.

Comment: @Masoud Thanks. rngCompany3 is var3. I forgot to replace it... Sorry.

Comment: @Josa Iracheta Before I set var3, it prints "$A$1:$A$10,$A$12:$A$15" and after nothing, because it doesn't go through the error.

Comment: You cannot print `MsgBox` on a range. Try this: `MsgBox(var3.Address)`

Comment: Maybe the value you're passing to Range() is of the wrong type

Comment: As @Masoud notes, use `var3.address`.  I am also unable to reproduce your error. I used your code, switching `rngCompany3` with `var3` and putting `msgBox (var3.address)`, and a message box correctly shows `$A$1:$A$10,$A$12:$A$15`.

Comment: Re, I tried as recommended :
 `Sub x()
     
    Dim var1 As Range
    Dim var2 As Range
    Dim var3 As Range
    
    Set var1 = Range("$A$1:$A$10")
    Set var2 = Range("$A$12:$A$15")
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(var1, var2).Address
        Set var3 = Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        MsgBox (var3.Address)
    End With
End Sub`  
but it still doesn't work... "Error 400" on the MsgBox ...

Answer (score 0):

.PrintArea expets the Adress of a Range()

```
.PrintArea = Me.Range("<RangeName>").Address
```